# tumblr PHP file_get_contents html not running

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get use tumblr as a CMS for a blog on my site. I believe i have the code to do so but I am having problems understanding how its outputting.

**CODE**

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://tecksup.tumblr.com/api/read?start=0&num=6');
echo $homepage;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Stands for tech support...<p>Updated Kline and added and API documentation to it. A few Easter eggs in the code(commands for kline). Added code blocks to the site.</p><p>-tecksup</p><p>Finished up the new Update feed. Also added Inderiad to the projects list. </p><p>-tecksup</p>
```

The code gives the text on the site, and the html is not getting run its just placed as text. As shown at this [link](http://dev.thecubecast.com/test/test_tum2.php). It looks like this is not the first question of its kind, although im mostly asking why the html in the output is not being run even though its an output from php. Does anybody know a method to run it as html or get the text out of the `<p>` so i can format it myself?

Thanks

Additionally the blog itself is located at [this link](http://tecksup.tumblr.com)

Comment: check the output of that link. you are calling the api and that returns a xml document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is returning XML with the post in which the < and > symbols of the post content are HTML entities (and are therefore shown literally by the browser). You can parse the content as XML and/or use `html_entity_decode()` on `$homepage` before outputting it.

Comment: you are correct on the one half of the question, now i just need to parse the xml to format it into blogs?

Comment: Use an extension like SimpleXMLParser, to get started: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php